# Pointing JSON objects to corresponding HTML divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

What is the exact way(javascript/jquery) to point Objects created in external JSON file to point and populate to their corresponding html divs. I am posting the complete code for html and JSON. Also refer to the image to get a clear idea of where the divs are and what data they hold.

```
      <! DOCTYPE html>
       <html>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
          <title>first2</title>
       <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jsoncss.css">
      </head>    
       <body>
          <div class="wrapper">
              <div class="MyAccountsLabel">
            <div class="MyAccountsLeft">My Accounts</div>
        </div>
        <div class="LeftSection">
            <div class="LeftSectionTopLeft">I Have (in 4 Accounts)</div>
            <div class="LeftSectionTopRight">+USD 13,700.00</div>
            <div class="MyMainSavings">
                <div class="MyMainSavingsTop">
                    <table class="MyMainSavingsTop">
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <td></td>
                    </table>
                    <div class="InterestRate">

                    </div>
                    <div class="regular">Regular</div>
                </div>
                <div class="MyMainSavingsBottom">
                    <table class="tablebottom">
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>

                            <td class="right"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td class="right"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td class="right"></td>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="MyEverydayExpenses">
                <div class="MyEverydayExpensesTop">
                    <table class="MyEverydayExpensesTop">
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <td></td>
                    </table>
                    <div class=".InterestRate">
                        <p></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="regular">Regular</div>
                </div>
                <div class="MyEverydayExpensesBottom">
                    <table class="tablebottom">
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td class="right"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td class="right"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td class="right"></td>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="MyDeposit">
                <div class="MyDepositTop">
                    <table class="MyDepositTop">
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <td></td>
                    </table>
                    <div class=".InterestRate"></div>
                    <div class="regular">Regular</div>
                </div>
                <div class="MyDepositBottom">
                    <table class="tablebottom">
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td class="right"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td class="right"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td class="right"></td>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="FavDeposit">
                <div class="FavDepositTop">
                    <table class="FavDepositTop">
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <td></td>
                    </table>
                    <div class=".InterestRate"></div>
                    <div class="regular">Regular</div>
                </div>
                <div class="FavDepositBottom">
                    <table class="tablebottom">
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td class="right"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td class="right"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td class="right"></td>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
           <div class="RightSection">
            <div class="RightSectionTopLeft">I Owe (from 3 Accounts)</div>
            <div class="RightSectionTopRight">-USD 33,4500.00</div>
            <div class="HomeLoan">
                <div class="HomeLoanTop">
                    <table class="HomeLoanTop">
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <td></td>
                    </table>
                    <div class=".InterestRate"></div>
                    <div class="regular">Regular</div>
                </div>
                <div class="HomeLoanBottom">
                    <table class="tablebottom">
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td class="right"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td class="right"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td class="right"></td>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="Ruby">
                <div class="RubyTop">
                    <table class="RubyTop">
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <td></td>
                    </table>
                    <div class=".InterestRate">

                    </div>
                    <div class="regular">Regular</div>
                </div>
                <div class="RubyBottom">
                    <table class="tablebottom">
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td class="right"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td class="right"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td class="right"></td>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="MyOverdraft">
                <div class="MyOverdraftTop">
                    <table class="MyOverdraftTop">
                        <tr>
                            <td>MyOverdraft</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <td></td>
                    </table>
                    <div class=".InterestRate">

                    </div>
                    <div class="regular"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="MyOverdraftBottom">
                    <table class="tablebottom">
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td class="right"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td class="right"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td class="right"></td>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
         </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

JSON file:

```
        var mainObject = {
        "Main": [{
          "I_Have": [{
              "MyMainSavings": {
                 "MyMainSavingsTop": {
                "AccountName": "MyMainSavings",
                "AccountNumber": "x726",
                "Balance": "USD 5,600.00",
                "Rate": ""
            },
            "MyMainSavingsBottom": [{
                "Available": "Available",
                "Value": "$4329"
            }, {
                "Clear": "Clear",
                "Value": "$3456"
            }, {
                "Hold": "Hold",
                "Value": "$5000"
            }]
        }
        }, {
        "MyEverydayExpenses": {
            "MyEverydayExpensesTop": {
                "AccountName": "MyMainSavings",
                "AccountNumber": "x726",
                "Balance": "USD 600.00",
                "Rate": ""
            },
            "MyEverydayExpensesBottom": [{
                "Available": "Available",
                "Value": "$4329"
            }, {
                "Clear": "Clear",
                "Value": "$3456"
            }, {
                "Hold": "Hold",
                "Value": "$7300"
            }]
        }
        }, {
        "FavDeposit": {
            "FavDepositTop": {
                "AccountName": "MyMainSavings",
                "AccountNumber": "x726",
                "Balance": "USD 5,000.00",
                "Rate": "@4.5%"
            },
            "FavDepositBottom": [{
                "MaturityValue": "Maturity Value",
                "Value": "$4009"
            }, {
                "Term": "Term",
                "Value": "$1156"
            }, {
                "MaturesOn": "Matures On",
                "Value": "$5000"
            }]
        }
       }, {
        "MyDeposit": {
            "MyDepositTop": {
                "AccountName": "MyMainSavings",
                "AccountNumber": "x726",
                "Balance": "USD 8,600.00",
                "Rate": "@4.5%"
            },
            "MyDepositBottom": [{
                "MaturityValue": "Maturity Value",
                "Value": "$4329"
            }, {
                "Term": "Term",
                "Value": "$3456"
            }, {
                "MaturesOn": "Matures On",
                "Value": "$5000"
            }]
           }
          }]
         }
```

IMAGE FOR REFERENCE

[image]

The html code has data in it. Essentially the data from html file should be removed and only come from json. By data I mean textual values appearing on the page. eg abc - This must not be the case, abc should come from json.

So the MyMainSavings div is corresponding to the MyMainSavings object in json, then MyMainSavingsTop div is corresponding to MyMainSavingsTop in json, so I want to populate the data in its corresponding element div through javascript/jquery. In short elements of same name should find themselves in the html file.

Comment: Have you tried anything to achieve this ?

Comment: As of now no i havent... But i have an idea which is as follows

mainObject.Main[0].I_Have[0].MyMainSavings.MyMainSavingsTop 

for (var i in mainObject.Main[0]) 
     console.log(i);

> I_Have

for (var i in mainObject.Main[0].I_Have[0]) 
     console.log(i);

> MyMainSavings

Comment: Implement that idea first before asking to do this for you..

Comment: I have tried but not getting anywhere... So help appreciated

Comment: Kindly edit your question and show us what you have tried..

Comment: Sir the above code is all i have got... I am going wrong somewhere logic-wise so unable to write the whole code

Answer (score 0):

Okay let me give you a brief idea so that you can start and then ask further:

1. create a function in your script and use AJAX to call your data file eg.

   function get_data(){
         var eurl=''your url';
         $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url:eurl,
           dataType:"json",
           async: true, 
           success:function(data){
                 if (data.text) {
               var JSONa = JSON.parse(data.text);
             }
             else{
               var JSONa = data;
             }

2.you now have the data so you can loop through it eg.

```
var emi = JSONa.response[0].data.options;
$.each(emi, function(key,value){});
```

3. Try printing out your json using loop and use this as you have same names in html so you can try using the data keys as selectors and append the corresponding value of key in it.

do not forget to call the function in the end.

```
get_data();
```

Hope this helps you to get started as of now.

Thanks!

Comment: this means as you have common names in html class and the same in json so instead  of manually writing selectors and the adding valu in html you can:    1. use keys as selectors of jquery and append values in it as data so that will automate your process

Comment: I am unable to load json data

Comment: any errors in console? Do check the ajax request and the corressponding response in your console

Comment: I have used the exact code that you gave in point 1. But how do i access the json object?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/…; <script> function get_data() { $.ajax( { type: "GET", url:"/json.json", dataType:"json", async: true, success:function(data) { if (data.text) { var JSONa = JSON.parse(data); } else { var JSONa = data; } } } ); } get_data(); </script> Can you please tell where am I going wrong? I am not getting an error but cannot see the json file loaded

Answer (score 0):

Parse this Json into a javascript variable as shown below:

```
 var json = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
```

And, using JQuery.each function you can loop as shown below

```
 jQuery.each(json.Main, function(idx, obj) {
     jQuery.each(obj.I_Have, function(idx1, obj1) {
          jQuery.each(obj1.MyMainSavings, function(idx2, obj2) {
                  jQuery.each(obj2.MyMainSavingsTop, function(idx3, obj3) {     $("table .MyMainSavingsTop tr").val(obj3.AccountName);

                   });  
            });

     });

  });
```

You can repeat the same for other elements as well.

Comment: Can you explain how should i load the external json file using ajax?

Comment: It depends on where you are obtaining your JSON from. Usually a jQuery.ajax() is all that is required to obtain the json from an external service.

Comment: I am getting json data from json.json file which is located on my desktop

Comment: In that case, this should do
`$.getJSON('your.json', function(data) {
        
    });`

Comment: Do i have to give link to ajax.googleapis.com...(for jquery)?

Comment: Yes, you will have to include the script file for jQuery to work.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

function get_data()
{ 
 $.ajax(
 { 
  type: "GET", 
  url:"/json.json",
  dataType:"json",
  async: true,  
  success:function(data)
   { 
    if (data.text) 
     { var JSONa = JSON.parse(data); } 
    else
     { var JSONa = data; }         
   }
 }
 );
}
get_data();
</script>
Can you please tell where am I going wrong? I am not getting an error but cannot see the json file loaded

Comment: Please use $.getJson instead of $.ajax.

Comment: How do i call the object that is in the json file? The firebug is not showing a  loaded json file.

Comment: -could you please help at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34737757/creating-nested-divs-in-jquery?noredirect=1#comment57221796_34737757

Comment: I am getting "e is undefined error" in the above code of nested each.